# read txt file and computing each lines average and write it on a new file

Tags: python-3.x

txt file is like this.

> 50 70 60
>
> 40 30 80
>
> 30 80 40

result txt file is like this.

> 50 70 60 60
>
> 40 30 80 50
>
> 30 80 40 50

I did like this so far. However I can't get result and also I cant' get the average

```
f=open("sample.txt")
lines=f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
    f2=open("result.txt", 'w')
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        each_score=line.split()
        f2.write(str(map(int, each_score)))
f.close()
f2.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had issues with your code so used what I could.

```
f=open("sample.txt")
lines=f.readlines()

f2=open("result.txt", 'w')

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == '':
        continue
    # Set each value as an integer into a list.
    each_score = [int(num) for num in line.split()]
    # Get average from sum/length.
    avg = int(sum(each_score) / len(each_score))
    # Create output list with item as str and include avg.
    output = [str(item) for item in (each_score + [avg])]
    # Finally write the line by joining the values.
    f2.write(' '.join(output) + '\n')

f.close()
f2.close()
```

Commented for your understanding.

output:

```
50 70 60 60
40 30 80 50
30 80 40 50
```